# How to register user activity in the application?

Tags: c#, database, wpf

I want to register and track user activities in the program. What is your suggestion? Through the database or on the program side?
On the database side, you can create triggers for changes to each table, but how can you use the username as a data retrieval record?
The program is being written with WpF and the database with SQL 2014

For better understanding, consider following scenario.

I have a table named "product" and a table named "companies". From the business logic we want to assign products to companies, which we ended up in a table "company_product". Now when a user insert new product and simultaneously assign it's companies, 2 table will be affected (the same goes for delete and update): "product" and "company_product" and we want to know:

what's inserted?

what's deleted?

what's updated to what?

And who has made these changes?

Answer (score 0):

I always set up a "TransactionLog" table that has columns like:

- TransactionId
- UserId
- Context
- Details
- TransactionDatetime

The combination of the User ID, Context and Details fields will allow you to capture all the details about what was done by what user. Keep Context shorter, something like a varchar(50), that is used for grouping but you can make Details varchar(max) if needed.

You can also add an additional context field if needed. Something like "Action" can be used to capture "update", "delete" or "create". For this, I would use "Context" to capture the name of the object that was being saved.

Comment: Insert into this table within the same transaction scope as the updates you are making to the entity data.

Comment: Also, a helpful thing to do is store the serialized object as a json string in the Details field. That way you have the transactional history of the state of that object.

Comment: I am a beginner, can you give more guidance and coding

Comment: Similar to how you are inserting data into your other tables, you would insert a record into the TransactionLog table as needed. If you really need it, post the code you are using to insert data into your other tables and I can show you how to tweak it to insert into a table like the one I described.